# Call an XMLUnit-test from another class

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I'm using XMLUnit to compare two XMLs. This works fine when i perform the test class manual as a jUnit test.

But now i want to call the tests i have from another class. I can perform the testMethod, but nothing happens

here an example for the class with the test:

```
public class Tests extends XMLTestCase{
    public void testForEquality() throws Exception {
        String myControlXML = "<msg><uuid>2376</uuid><uuuid>23767</uuuid></msg>";
        String myTestXML = "<msg><uuid>2376</uuid><uuuid>23767</uuuid></msg>";
        assertXMLEqual(myControlXML, myTestXML);
    }
}
```

here what i have tried to call it from another class:

```
public class testExternalCall{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tests compareTest= new Tests ();
        compareTest.testForEquality();  
    }   
}
```

Blue

Comment: What is the error message ? Looks like you want to implement some common reusable test util methods. If so you could extend your common functionality into your child class using extends keyword.

Comment: There is no error message. Good idea  but is in that case not possible, because i extend something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that... Your test method would actually be called as a simple Java code and as there are no failures it would simple pass the test and would not print anything in your testExternalCall.java.

Add a `System.out.println("Finished...");`

in your Tests.java last line. This would gets printed.

Or change your code like below to some different value the test would fail and you would get the failure logs.

```
String myTestXML = "<msg><uuid>2376</uuid><uuuid>23767XXXXXXXX</uuuid></msg>";
```